# How to Get HiddenField value using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am new to javascript. I am going to show visitor counter of website. I have made c# code to enter the values of the counter into the database. After that I fetch count values from the database. This count value from the database is my hit count for the website. I want to show it using javascript with the asp control hidden field. But it doesn't display anything. How do I solve this problem? I have tried with following code:

//Hitcount.aspx file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getTotalCount() {
            alert(document.getElementById('hdTotalCount').value());
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="getTotalCount();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdTotalCount" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

//Server Side code

```
if (!IsPostBack == true)
{
    //SQL Query to fetch total count
    hdTotalCount.Value = 21;  //21 is the SQL query result
}
```

Comment: why should you use HiddenField to show something, just use other control like asp:Label for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Control.ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it gets the control ID for HTML markup that is generated by ASP.NET.

Also `value` is a property not a function.

Use

```
 alert(document.getElementById('<%= hdTotalCount.ClientID %>').value);
```

Comment: Or he could set ClientIDMode to Static ?

Comment: @sh1rts, Personally I don't recommend ClientIDMode as Static

Comment: I have used <%= hdTotalCount.ClientID %> , but actually alert pop up also not  displaying

Comment: @user1659510, Did you used my exact code? You must be getting some error in console.

Comment: @Satpal - any reason why not ? ClientIDMode is a useful addition to the framework, means we can avoid having to add bits of server-side code into markup.

Comment: @sh1rts, we need to careful with ClientMode as static is at times using it with usercontrols we end have duplicate ID which makes HTML invalid. However in OP's situation its was perfect solution. As he is a beginner I avoid that. Hope you get my point of view.